# Swift Speech framework transcription Array always contains one transcription only

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, avaudiosession, speech

I`m using Speech framework to transcript user response in a quiz game. We present a image of an animal and the user have to say the name of the animal. When I evaluate user response... "result.transcriptions" only have 1 transcription, the same as "result.bestTranscription". Are there any solution to get multiple response options?

Here is my Code

```
       if recognitionTask != nil {
            recognitionTask?.finish()
            recognitionTask = nil
        }

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        } catch {
            print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
        }

        recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

        let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode

        guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
            fatalError("Unable to create an SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object")
        }

        recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true

        recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { [weak self] result, error in

            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error)
            }

            guard let result = result else { return }

            if result.bestTranscription.formattedString.lowercased() == self.searchTerm.lowercased() {
                    found = true
                    self.response = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            } else {
                    result.transcriptions.forEach { transcription in
                        if transcription.formattedString.lowercased() == self.searchTerm.lowercased() {
                            self.response = transcription.formattedString
                            found = true
                        }
                        debugPrint("Transcription")
                        debugPrint(transcription.formattedString)
            }
        })
```

Comment: It's not clear to me about **what** you want from multiple responses. However, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092593/how-to-handle-homophones-in-speech-recognition

Comment: Thanks for the response CodeBender, My problem is the same as this link, but I can´t redefine our architecture. User always only say one or two words, and Speech can't put the correct answer, with context's help, because it hasn`t any thing to compare. The ideal way is that Speech return alternatives in transcription array or "alternativeSubstrings" field... But I didn't find the solution :S always is nil.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong here, and I'd guess the lack of alternative interpretations is simply because it's very confident in the response, being such a short string. I wonder if you'd see more transcriptions if you tested a longer string? Other thoughts - try setting SFSpeechRecognitionTaskHint on the recognizer to dictation. Last thought is to set shouldReportPartialResults to true to see if any of the partial results give you what you need.